# variable not defined but I had already defind the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's a simple program of adding two numbers :

```
1 print("Testing again")
2 print(a)
3 a = input()
4 print(a)
5 b = input()
6 c = int(a) + int(b)
```

I am a beginner in using vscode. So I am trying to resolve the problem.
code error

```
>>> print(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Show the relevant code properly formatted in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Maybe it would make more sense if the error message said name 'a' is not defined **yet**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = input()  <--  Definition

print(a) <--  Calling
```

if you do

```
print(a)
```

before defining

```
a = something
```

a is never defined at that point and will give you error.

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

You *use* `a` in line 2 before *assigning* to it in line 3:

```
1 print("Testing again")
2 print(a)
3 a = input()
4 print(a)
5 b = input()
6 c = int(a) + int(b)
```

You can probably just get rid of line 2 since you print `a` on line 4 (after it's set). Or, if you wanted to print both variables, make sure you do it after setting them:

```
1 print("Testing again")
2 a = input()
3 print(a)
4 b = input()
5 print(b)
6 c = int(a) + int(b)
7 print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is called an interpreted language. Python runs code like line-1, line-2, and so on.

So if you define a variable in line-2 and print it line-1 python does not recognize it as defined variable.

So your should be like this

`1 print("Testing again")
2 a = input()
3 print(a)
4 b = input()
5 print(b)
6 c = int(a) + int(b)
7 print(c)`